# Detecting the max value from an array and printing it as text instead of value

Tags: python

> Hello all, I have been self-learning python for the past week using some audiovisual content and I am trying to solve advent of code, the problem requires to input some values for several elfs, add those values individually and check the one with the highest number.
> I manage to get to the point that I can determine which one has the highest load my doubt is how can i add that to any new variable and print it with losing the one with the highest number.
> This is the code I got so far

```
`#input number of items caried by each elf and how many calories each item has
elf_1 = input("insert item calories of elf 1(separated by space):")
elf_2 = input("insert item calories of elf 2(separated by space):")
elf_3 = input("insert item calories of elf 3(separated by space):")
elf_4 = input("insert item calories of elf 4(separated by space):")
elf_5 = input("insert item calories of elf 5(separated by space):")

#transform string values into intengers
    #Elf 1
variable_1 = elf_1.split()
str_to_int_1 = list(map(int, variable_1))
    #Elf 2
variable_2 = elf_2.split()
str_to_int_2 = list(map(int, variable_2))
    #Elf 3
variable_3 = elf_3.split()
str_to_int_3 = list(map(int, variable_3))
    #Elf 4
variable_4 = elf_4.split()
str_to_int_4 = list(map(int, variable_4))
    #Elf 5
variable_5 = elf_5.split()
str_to_int_5 = list(map(int, variable_5))

#obtaining the total number of calories carried by each elf
total_1 = sum(str_to_int_1)
total_2 = sum(str_to_int_2)
total_3 = sum(str_to_int_3)
total_4 = sum(str_to_int_4)
total_5 = sum(str_to_int_5)

#checking the elf with the highest number of calories
calorie_table = (total_1, total_2, total_3, total_4, total_5)
highest_calorie = max(calorie_table)
print("The elf with the highest calories is: " + highest_calorie)`
```

for example, imagine total 3 has the highest amount of calories, how can I print something like "The elf with the highest calories is: elf no3" instead of the calorie amount.

I tried transforming the total values to text variables but I lose track of the one who has the highest amount of calories.

Thank you for your support

Comment: max() can be used to find the highest value in a list. Index() can be used to give you the index of a value in a list. Str() can give you the string value of an integer. Good luck

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a very unconvenient approach to repeat code to do the same things 5 times. Whenever you deal with such repetition, it's better to use data structures like `list` or `dict`, and process it with `for` loops, `while` loops and functions. For example, your code can be shortened to this:

```
num_of_elves = 5
max_calories = 0
elf_with_max_calories = -1
for i in range(num_of_elves):
  elf_items = input(f"insert item calories of elf {i+1}(separated by space):")
  elf_items = elf_items.split()
  elf_items = list(map(int, elf_items))
  elf_calories = sum(elf_items)
  if elf_calories > max_calories:
    max_calories = elf_calories
    elf_with_max_calories = i+1

print("The elf with the highest calories is: ", max_calories)
print("For elf #", elf_with_max_calories)
```

### EDIT:

Regarding the comment, if you want to read the number of elves from the console and check that the values is valid (in your case a positive integer), you can check first if the input values contains only numbers, after that we will know that it can be converted to an integer using `int` function. Then we can check if the value is positive:

```
  string = input("How many elves?: ")
  # if string contains only digits, and is a positive integer
  if string.isdigit() and int(string) > 0: 
    num_of_elves = int(string)
  else:
    print("You didn't enter a valid number (positive integer)")
    quit()
```

It would be more convenient if you kept asking for the value until the user inputs a correct value, for this you can use an ininite loop. It will `break` when the value is correct, and then the rest of the program will continue

```
while True: # repeat infinitely
  string = input("How many elves?: ")
  # if string contains only digits, and is a positive integer
  if string.isdigit() and int(string) > 0: 
    num_of_elves = int(string)
    break # stop repeating when input is correct
  else: # not a valid number
    print("You didn't enter a valid number (positive integer)")
```

Comment: one quick question imagine I have X number os elfs can I make something like while "num_of_elves != NULL"?
Sorry to bother.

Comment: @GonçaloRocha I edited my answer with that